# Is the sentence "The ice cream was so good that he ate all of it" a run-on sentence? (is there a name for this grammatical construct?)

Tags: run-on-sentence

I was claiming that the sentence

> The ice cream was so good, he ate all of it.     ... (1)

is a run-on sentence.  And somebody pointed out that

> The ice cream was so good he ate all of it.      ... (2)

sounds like it is *not* a run-on sentence. I think the reason is that it sounds very much like:

> The ice cream was so good that he ate all of it. ... (3)

and this doesn't sound like a run-on sentence. Are they run-on sentences? If (3) is not, is it a particular proper grammatical construct that makes it not a run-on sentence? (because there are two clauses (with verbs) and not connected by a conjunction, semicolon, or separated by a period `.`)

The question was closed because a definition of run-on sentence was needed. The definition is:

> A run-on sentence occurs when two or more independent clauses (also known as complete sentences) are connected improperly.

Comment: {I've adjusted tenses for better balance.} No and/or yes. If you intend 'The ice cream was so good, he ate all of it.' to have the sense 'The ice cream was _so_ [ie _really, sooo_] good./! He ate all of it./!' the commaed version _is_ a run-on sentence, and (though this is not always the case) unacceptable here. This is because the default reading is 'The ice cream was so good[,] he ate all of it.' being a deleted variant of 'The ice cream was so good that he ate all of it.'. The comma is optional, and (1) and (2) are both grammatical, but ...

Comment: the default reading is the same as for (3): neither (1) nor (2) is then a run-on sentence. / If you want the 'two related statements' rather than the 'resultative', 'so good that he did ...'  reading, you need something more heavy-duty than a comma: a semicolon or a dash if you want to retain a single sentence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It took me awhile to see what you were getting at. Yes, if the 2 pieces were meant to be read separately, they should be separated with a full stop or at least a semicolon, not just a comma. If parsed as antecedent-consequent pairs, all variants presented are grammatical.

Comment: The three different ways of writing it really just net down to two in speech (whether there's a pause after "good"), since in many people's diction, the optional word "that" (only valid *without* that pause) would be so "de-emphasised" you wouldn't necessarily hear it anyway. And it seems to me all *native* speakers would understand the significance of that (pragmatically *unlikely*) pause without being consciously aware of the syntactic structure or terminology.

Comment: Please define "run-on sentence".

Answer (score 1):

In sentence 3, "that" is a subordinating conjunction that introduces a result clause. Therefore it is not a run-on sentence.  See the entry for "that" at Webster's online dictionary: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/that

As the commenters noted, sentences 1and 2 are perfectly acceptable versions of 3, at least in spoken English. But I would generally avoid them in more formal writing.

However, as some of the comments have alluded to, depending on emphasis sentence 1 might be heard as 2 sentences. The only instance I can think of when sentence 1 would be heard as a single sentence is when the comma is used as a dramatic pause. In this case, you would overemphasize "so good" so that the listener would expect a pause before "that." If the pause is not expected, then I think most native speakers would hear two separate sentences.

Comment: thanks. I also thought about (1) and (2) if it is spoken... they sound alright... the thing is, if spoken, it is hard to say whether it is a comma or period in between.  Let's say, it is written, maybe as if it is written as dialogs in a novel.